# Is RL-AC circuit's current higher at the first time?

Tags: ac, inductance

I've solved the differential equation of the current function of RL-AC circuit.

And then I've checked the plot(graph) and found that the first period of the current is higher.

[image]

Why is this happen? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like it hasn't had a chance to go negative yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the inductance. If you simulated it with the AC being applied at the point when the waveform peaked, you would see the behaviour you desired.

You must consider that the current in an inductor lags its terminal voltage by 90º when things have settled down and this means that applying a sinewave at the point it is zero volts means the peak current will be higher on the first cycle.

This is the most common problem with inrush current on power transformers - that initial peak causes the magnetic core to saturate and fuses blow. Always best to apply power on a peak of the waveform.

Comment: I really want to vote up, but I can't because my reputation isn't higher than 15. I'll vote up this answer next time.

Comment: And I've found that this is related with transient current.